# No se aplica el margin y padding 0 en el Normalize. ¿Alguien sabe el motivo?

Tags: html5, css3, margin, padding

En el *normalize* he aplicado, con el selector universal, el `padding`, `margin` y `box-sizing 0`, pero esto no se aplica. Ya que al guardar no puedo observar que el título y el párrafo estén juntos.

[image: Imagen de prueba]

¿Alguien sabe el motivo?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes [inspeccionar el elemento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium), para ver que estilo está interfiriendo.

Comment: Checa si la ruta y el nombre del archivo normalize.css están correctos, a veces la ruta o una letra falta y pues destroza todo.

Answer (score 2):

Si vienes del curso de Dalto, me pasó lo mismo, luego me di cuenta de que Dalto usaba un h2 y yo un h1, que, como te dijo Narciso, el h1 tiene margenes y paddings aparte. Igualmente, espero que ya seas un crack programando webs (llegué re tarde ndeah).

Igual si quieres que tus h1 usen el padding 0, solo basta que en estilos.css crees un

```
h1 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que otra librería css, después de tu normalize, tome el control del estilo.
En head de tu html debe estar primero el link de normalize.css y luego otro estilo css. Estos otros estilos puede contener el estilo, lo cual toma el control porque este estilo está último.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="otros-estilos.css"> 
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que, si tú estilo.css está después de normalize.css, y si tiene un padding y margin diferente, éste será aplicado.

Comment: :c el normalize lo tengo tengo después del estilo css. Ya cambié su posición en repetidas ocasiones, pero nada :c

Comment: Entonces crea un nuevo estilo para el título con: margin:0 y padding:0. Porque los H1 (si es tu caso), tiene su propio margen

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, pero sigue igual :/ no surte efecto :/